# React native rest with apisauce cookie

Tags: rest, react-native, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using in one of my project React Native with ApiSauce as rest client.
There is a lot of examples with parsing response, etc. I have got two questions:
1. It is possible to dump let's say with console.log request that was sent to endpoint?
2. what about cookie? It is possible to setup cookie that should be sent with request and read cookie that returned with response?

regards
i